# Gmail auto forward as other account

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

In **Settings → Accounts**, I have another account for **Send mail as**. And in **Forwarding and POP/IMAP**, I enabled the auto forward.

The problem is, when Gmail auto forwarded it, didn't used the "other account". Why?

Answer (score 1):

The  `send mail as` setting is used to send new mail, respond to email, or forward a message to one or more people. It looks like you are sending email from that other address.

The `Forwarding` in `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` sends all your incoming email to another address. You use this if you want to send all your email to a new address.